# Regular expression to clean webscraped text

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some information for a wikipedia page and I am using Beautiful soup load the text into Python but I seem to be having trouble stripping out all of the un-necessary tags using regular expressions.

This is a sample of the output of the text from Beautiful soup

```
[<td colspan="3">
</td>, <td valign="top" width="400">
<ul><li><a href="/wiki/Aach,_Baden-W%C3%BCrttemberg" title="Aach, Baden-Württemberg">Aach</a> (<a href="/wiki/Baden-W%C3%BCrttemberg" title="Baden-Württemberg">Baden-Württemberg</a>)</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Aachen" title="Aachen">Aachen</a> (<a href="/wiki/North_Rhine-Westphalia" title="North Rhine-Westphalia">North Rhine-Westphalia</a>)</li>
```

Ideally I would like to have the city (which is assigned to title), and the region (which is just before the end of the line).

Any help would be most appreciated!

```
rows = soup.find_all('td')
list_rows = []

#remove html tags
for row in rows:
    cells = row.find_all('li')
    str_cells = str(cells)
    clean = re.compile('<.*?>')
    clean2 = (re.sub(clean, '', str_cells))
    list_rows.append(clean2)
print(clean2)
```

Comment: Can you share the URL of the wikipedia page?

Comment: So are the regions the text before the closing anchor tags (`</a>`)?

Comment: Sure:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_and_towns_in_Germany

Comment: In some cases yes where the regions are a hyperlink but in other cases the regions are just before the closing anchor tags (</li>)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.find_next_sibling()` method in this case:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_and_towns_in_Germany'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

for li in soup.select('td[width="400"] li'):
    city = li.select_one('a')
    if city.find_next_sibling('a'):
        region = city.find_next_sibling('a').text
    else:
        region = city.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip()
    print('{: <30}{}'.format(city.text, re.findall(r'[^()]+', region)[0]))
```

Prints:

```
Aach                          Baden-Württemberg
Aachen                        North Rhine-Westphalia
Aalen                         Baden-Württemberg
Abenberg                      Bavaria
Abensberg                     Bavaria
Achern                        Baden-Württemberg
Achim                         Lower Saxony
Adelsheim                     Baden-Württemberg
Adenau                        Rhineland-Palatinate
Adorf                         Saxony
Ahaus                         North Rhine-Westphalia
Ahlen                         North Rhine-Westphalia
Ahrensburg                    Schleswig-Holstein
Aichach                       Bavaria
Aichtal                       Baden-Württemberg
Aken (Elbe)                   Saxony-Anhalt
Albstadt                      Baden-Württemberg
Alfeld                        Lower Saxony
Allendorf (Lumda)             Hesse
Allstedt                      Saxony-Anhalt

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej, out of curiousity is it better to use Beautiful soup to clean webscraped text or to use Regular expressions?

Comment: @JayDoe Better parse HTML through BeautifulSoup. Parsing HTML through regexp is never good idea in majority of cases.

Comment: Just to confirm, the 'select', 'select_one' and 'find_next_sibling' methods are all Beautiful Soup methods? thanks Jay

Comment: @JayDoe Yes, they are BeautifulSoup's methods. The documentation is here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ Make sure you are using the latest version!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two regexes to do what you want:

This regular expression seems like it will get you all of those town name title attributes, although it may need some tweaking if there are different special characters in town names. This will catch spaces, dashes, and commas.
`title=\"([\w ,-]+)\">[\w]+</a>[^\)]`

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/sUMr7K/2)

This one should get you the region names in the first capture group, although the same warning about special characters applies:
`([\w ,-]+)(</a>)?\)</li>`

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/oxsDCC/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the link - I will use it as a learning resource and to play around with regular expressions.